# How to get original collection from an IQueryable<T>

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

Consider the following:

```
T[] itemArray = // initialized values
IQueryable<T> itemQuery = itemArray.AsQueryable().Where(*/some query*/).Skip(5).Etc() ...
```

Is it possible to get the underlying collection or dataset (in this case `itemArray`) from `itemQuery`?  It seems to me that if when the query expression is evaluated, it must be evaluated against the original collection and therefore that collection must be stored in or referenced by the IQueryable.

How can this be done?

NOTE:
This is part of a larger project with the MongoDB linq driver (from 10gen) where we are trying to extract the original MongoCollection from an IQueryable that is based on the mongo collection.  Although we are using IQueryable<> specifically with respect to MongoDB, the answer to this question should be inherent to IQueryable<> and therefore independent of the MongoDB drivers.

Answer (score 3):

The `IQueryable` most likely does have a reference to the underlying collection (possibly through a number of layers of indirection), but it won't be publicly exposed, so you won't be able to access it, at least not in any way that I would consider *reasonable* and not a very, very messy hack.

Comment: +1 - I believe the EF Linq provider just stores any filters, etc. in order to project SQL, so there may be no way to get to the entire table with an `IQueryable` reference.  I'd hope the MongoDB provider is similar and doesn't filter the data in memory.

Answer (score 0):

No, each query is executed independently, and all you're left with is the result set of the query itself. There is nothing within the memory object that contains the original collection nor any accessible reference to the original collection. Considering that the original collection may now be null or out of scope, this would be dangerous to allow even. If you need to the original collection, you will need to keep it in scope until you're completely finished with it.

Comment: Well, the original collection has to exist *somewhere*.  queries here are using deferred execution, so it is merely defining how to extract data from the collection, it's not actually extracting it until you try to enumerate it.  It therefore needs to have a reference to the actual collection (at least indirectly).

Comment: @Servy: Yah, I put in an edit with the word "accessible". There's a reference to the original collection for execution purposes, but there is no accessible reference. I am not 100% certain, but I believe once the execution is committed this reference is dumped. Don't quote me on that, though. It just seems to me that I read something to that effect somewhere (or at least something that led me to believe it :)

Comment: While it's certainly possible that a custom query provider could do that, no sensible one would.  For starters, you can enumerate [most] queries multiple times, so intentionally discarding the information you need to enumerate "yourself" would prevent that (which none of the standard providers do).  As I've said in my answer, you probably can't (in practice) get the reference out of the `IQueryable`, but it's in there (somewhere).

Comment: @Servy: Once the execution occurs, new data is loaded into separate memory space. The original reference only needs to be alive long enough for execution to occur. Though now you've piqued my curiosity. I'm going to have to run some scoping tests to see what happens with the deferred execution when a source collection goes out of scope after execution occurs and before.

Comment: As I've said, the query will hold onto a reference to the source collection for its entire lifetime, so, by definition, the source collection can't go out of scope before the query occurs.  Some variable that references the actual collection (which the actual programmer has access to) might go out of scope, but the underlying collection (an array in this case) can't go out of scope until the queryable is gone.  If it did (possibly through mean unsafe code) then the query would break, as it would be querying data that no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

This is cheating, but maybe it makes sense in your context:

```
interface IReferencedQueryable<T> : IQueryable<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> Source { get; }
}

static class IReferencedQueryableExtensions
{
    public static IReferencedQueryable<T> AsReferencedQueryable<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return ReferencedQueryable.From(source);
    }

    class ReferencedQueryable<T> : IReferencedQueryable<T>
    {
        public IEnumerable<T> Source { get; private set; }

        ReferencedQueryable(IEnumerable<T> source)
        {
            Source = source;
        }

        static IReferencedQueryable<T> From(IEnumerable<T> source)
        {
            return new ReferencedQueryable(source);
        }

        // all the IQueryable members would be 
        // implemented through AsQueryable()
        // ...
    }

    public static IReferencedQueryable<T> Where<T>(
        this IReferencedQueryable<T> source, 
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return ReferencedQueryable.From(
            ((IQueryable<T>)source).Where(predicate));
    }

    // do the same for all the Linq extension methos you want to support
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
T[] itemArray = // initialized values
var itemQuery = itemArray.AsReferencedQueryable()
                         .Where(*/some query*/)
                         .Skip(5)
                         .Etc() ...
```

When you need your source sequence you can access it through the `Source` member, possibly through an `as` cast.

```
var s = itemQuery.Source;
```